# "INVALID_SIGNATURE" in yelp API request

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, http-status-code-400, yelp

i'm getting the following error when trying to make a get request to the yelp API (v2):

```
/**/cb({"error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE", "description": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: 

GET\u0026http%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com%2Fv2%2Fsearch\u0026_%3D1442688327244%26callback%3Dcb%26location%3DSan%252BFrancisco%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXI67kdnHbzVrvcY6jAfQKQ%26oauth_consumer_secret%3DWg3-20tFWx82F952ORa7ZIotsVE%26oauth_nonce%3DXQbTeX%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1442688327%26oauth_token%3Dazu7S1QVuyIhn-LrHvBWIMR99OXceUyY%26term%3Dfood"}})
```

Here is the request that I am making:

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=cb&callback=cb&location=San%2BFrancisco&oauth_consumer_key=XI67kdnHbzVrvcY6jAfQKQ&oauth_consumer_secret=Wg3-20tFWx82F952ORa7ZIotsVE&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_token=azu7S1QVuyIhn-LrHvBWIMR99OXceUyY&term=food&oauth_timestamp=1442688327&oauth_nonce=XQbTeX&oauth_signature=boKHi1X0rcUfcic8EgOVpXQHi4M%3D&_=1442688327244
```

How can I solve this error? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You add `callback=cb` two times remove one and url should be alphabet order

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=cb&location=San%2BFrancisco&oauth_consumer_key=XI67kdnHbzVrvcY6jAfQKQ&oauth_consumer_secret=Wg3-20tFWx82F952ORa7ZIotsVE&oauth_nonce=XQbTeX&oauth_signature=boKHi1X0rcUfcic8EgOVpXQHi4M%3D&_=1442688327244&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1442688327&oauth_token=azu7S1QVuyIhn-LrHvBWIMR99OXceUyY&term=food
```